# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

I have a chrome extension which monitors the browser in a special way, sending some data to a web-server. In the current configuration this is the localhost. So the content script contains a code like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data)...
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.send();
```

where url parameter is 'http://localhost/ctrl?params' (or http://127.0.0.1/ctrl?params - it doesn't matter).

Manifest-file contains all necessary permissions for cross-site requests.

The extension works fine on most sites, but on one site I get the error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/ctrl?params. Origin http://www.thissite.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I've tried several permissions which are proposed here (`*://*/*`, `http://*/*`, and `<all_urls>`), but no one helped to solve the problem.

So, the question is what can be wrong with this specific site (apparently there may be another sites with similar misbehaviour, and I'd like to know the nature of this), and how to fix the error?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which site you see this error on? It may be using Content Security Policy (https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html) to prevent the data from being loaded.

Comment: Here is the site - www.wix.com.

Comment: Mihai, do you mean that the "Content Security Policy" of a site has precedence of the extension permissions? Then how can we write a reliable extension at all? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Among specific HTTP-headers coming from the site I see only the following ones: `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` and `X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block`. Does any of them violate extension's permissions? I didn't find related info in the Internet.

Comment: Those headers should not be affecting the behavior of your extension (I'm also not seeing them in the www.wix.com response, are they for a specific sub-page of the site). Is it possible to share your extension (and/or create a minimal version that just replicates this problem)?

Comment: I grabbed these headers from Chrome's har file after opening main page of the site, so it is strange that you do not see them. I'll try to prepare a simplified version of the extension - how can I post it?

Comment: I have the test extension to reproduce the problem. I'm not sure the site allows for exchanging with such stuff. Any ideas?

Comment: Feel free to email it to me (mihaip at chromium dot org).

Comment: Mihai, I'd like just make sure that you have received my e-mail sent 2 days ago. I'm using jsonp as a replacement and can go "as is", but I'm curious did you succeed in reproducing the strange behaviuor? If yes, should we file a bug to Chrome?

Comment: Stan: I'm not seeing an email from you? What address did you send it from?

Comment: I've just sent the duplicate from other 2 addresses. Hope this'll help to break through antispam filters. Otherwise I'll upload the stuff somewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(tl;dr: see two possible workarounds at the end of the answer)

This is the series of events that happens, which leads to the behavior that you see:

1. http://www.wix.com/ begins to load
2. It has a `<script>` tag that asynchronously loads the Facebook Connect script:

   ```
   (function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script');
     e.type = 'text/javascript';
     e.src = document.location.protocol +
       '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     e.async = true;
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
   }());
   ```
3. Once the HTML (but not resources, including the Facebook Connect script) of the wix.com page loads, the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires. Since your content script uses `"run_at" : "document_end"`, it gets injected and run at this time.
4. Your content script runs the following code (as best as I can tell, it wants to do the bulk of its work after the `load` event fires):

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
     // code that eventually does the cross-origin XMLHttpRequest
   };
   ```
5. The Facebook Connect script loads, and it has its own `load` event handler, which it adds with this snippet:

   ```
   (function() {
     var oldonload=window.onload;
     window.onload=function(){
       // Run new onload code
       if(oldonload) {
         if(typeof oldonload=='string') {
           eval(oldonload);
         } else {
           oldonload();
         }
       }
     };
   })();
   ```

   (this is the first key part) **Since your script set the `onload` property, `oldonload` is your script's load handler.**
6. Eventually, all resources are loaded, and the `load` event handler fires.
7. Facebook Connect's `load` handler is run, which run its own code, and then invokes `oldonload`. (this is the second key part) **Since the page is invoking your `load` handler, it's not running it in your script's [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment), but in the page's "main world"**. Only the script's isolated world has cross-origin `XMLHttpRequest` access, so the request fails.

To see a simplified test case of this, see [this page](http://persistent.info/chromium/test-cases/co-xhr/onload-wrapper.html) (which mimics http://www.wix.com), which loads [this script](http://persistent.info/chromium/test-cases/co-xhr/onload-wrapper.js) (which mimics Facebook Connect). I've also put up simplified versions of the [content script](http://persistent.info/chromium/test-cases/co-xhr/contentscript.js) and [extension manifest](http://persistent.info/chromium/test-cases/co-xhr/manifest.json).

The fact that your `load` handler ends up running in the "main world" is most likely a manifestation of [Chrome bug 87520](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87520) (the bug has security implications, so you might not be able to see it).

There are two ways to work around this:

1. Instead of using `"run_at" : "document_end"` and a `load` event handler, you can use the default running time (`document_idle`, after the document loads) and just have your code run inline.
2. Instead of adding your `load` event handler by setting the `window.onload` property, use `window.addEventListener('load', func)`. That way your event handler will not be visible to the Facebook Connect, so it'll get run in the content script's isolated world.

Answer (score 1):

The access control origin issue you're seeing is likely manifest in the headers for the response (out of your control), rather than the request (under your control).

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a policy for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control), set in the header. Using PHP, for example, you use a set of headers like the following to enable CORS:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://blah.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Disposition, attachment');
```

If sounds like that if the server is setting a specific origin in this header, then your [Chrome extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) is following the directive to allow cross-domain (POST?) requests from only that domain.

Comment: If it would be confirmed, then it looks like a bug in Chrome, because extension permissions should allow cross-origin requests. I don't think it is normal for such situation to involve a "manual" http-header processing via `webRequest`.